# Obtengo el error 'float' object has no attribute 'min'

Tags: python

Estoy tratando de sacar la distancia mínima entre dos puntos dentro de un ciclo `for`, pero obtengo el error:

> 'float' object has no attribute 'min'

Este el código que me produce el error:

```
def getNearestNeighbor(df, point):
    for i in range(0, 3):
        for j in range(0,3):
            var=(i,j)
            minima=(dist(var, point)).min()
    return minima
```

Agradecería mucho sus ayudas

Comment: Es fácil, `math.dist()` siempre te va a dar un objeto tipo `float`, este tipo no tiene ningún método llamada `min()` ;)

Answer (score 3):

Para calcular el mínimo, necesitas un juego de datos, y en tu código estás calculando el mínimo de un solo valor (un `float`), que no tiene mucho sentido.

Para calcular la distancia mínima, primero genera una lista de distancias a todos los posibles destinos:

```
[dist((x, y), point) for x in range(0, 3) for y in range(0, 3)]
```

que es una forma abreviada del clásico `for` anidado:

```
lista = []
for i in range(0, 3):
    for j in range(0,3):
        lista.append(dist(i, j), point)
```

y luego calcula el minimo de eso:

```
def getNearest(df, point):
    return min([dist((x, y), point) for x in range(0, 3) for y in range(0, 3)])
```

Ignoro para que usas el parámetro `df`.